# List is not being updated

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a list for which i am trying to add rows using sp services.The status message is coming as true but the list is not updating.

The list has 6 columns including title and all are created with text format(Column names are same as given in spservices valupairs).

Here is my piece of code:

```
            $().SPServices({

            operation:"UpdateListItems",
            async:false,
            listName:"DetailsOfEmployee",
            batchCmd:"New", 
            valuepairs:[["Title","Mr"],["Employee Id","593026"],["Employee Name","Anusha"],["Age","23"],["Company","TCS"],["Salary","28000"]], 
            completefunc:function (xData, Status){
            alert(Status);
            }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use static name aka internal name of columns in value pairs. The internal name of column `Employee Id` may be `Employee_x0020_Id` and for `Employee Name` it may be `Employee_x0020_Name`

> StaticName
>
> StaticName (as opposed to DisplayName) means the underlying column
>   name, e.g., Region_x0020_Name. This is also sometimes called the
>   'internal name' for the column. The DisplayName would be Region Name,
>   i.e., the name of the column which is shown on forms and as the header
>   in list views. Probably the easiest way to determine the StaticName if
>   you don't know it is to go to List Settings and click on the column
>   name link. When you get to the column properties page, check the URL.
>   It will end in something like this:
>   /*layouts/FldEdit.aspx?List=%7B37920121%2D19B2%2D4C77%2D92FF%2D8B3E07853114%7D&Field=Potential%5Fx0020%5FValue
>   The StaticName is the value for the Field parameter at the end. This
>   is a little tricky because some of the characters are further encoded.
>   Any occurrences of '%5F' need to be replaced with an underscore '*'.
>   Examples:
>
> Potential%5Fx0020%5FValue -> Potential_x0020_Value
>   Child%5Fx0020%5FSite%5Fx0020%5FName -> Child_x0020_Site_x0020_Name

Comment: Awsome now the code is working thanks a lot :)                     but i am geeting an error                                 Object doesn't support this property or method ScriptResource.axd